# Post and Get Multiple Data via jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, post, methods, get

i post one data to php via jquery
but i want get multiple data and echo each data

jquery code :

```
$.post('form.php', {id:id_prc}, function(data){
    $('.content').html(data);
});
```

my php code :

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$basket='basket';
$dvd='dvd';
}
```

$basket and $dvd is different data and i want get this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post('form.php', {id:id_prc}, function(data){
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $('.content').html('basket: '+response.basket+'dvd: '+response.dvd);
}); 


if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$x['basket']='basket value';
$x['dvd']='dvd value';
echo json_encode($x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery

```
var formData = {
    'id' : $("#someID").text(),
    'basket': $("#basketID").text(),
    'dvd': $("#dvdID").text()
};

$.post('form.php', formData, function(data){
    $('.content').html(data);
});
```

Your php code,

```
if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
    $basket=$_POST['basket'];
    $dvd=$_POST['dvd'];
}
```